# custom parameter not getting returned in PAYPAL recursive transaction

Tags: php, paypal

Am going to implement the paypal in the form of user subscription...
Bellow code runs fine...
Transaction also works fine...

But am not getting back the '`custom parameters`' which i have send(as shown in following code of form)...

```
<form name="_xclick" id="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@xxx.com">
 <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <!-- Identify the subscription. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $description; ?>">
    <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="<?php echo $trial_period; ?>">
    <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $return_domain;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $cancel_return;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" value="<?php echo $return_domain;?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $serialized_cust_par;?>" />
     </form>
```

Comment: What you are getting in response ? what abt the others like notify_url etc ???

Comment: `Array ( [auth] => AsnETBKr3hqf2gmyxTwXE50Z3K3y6nX6d34Ufv0RUp78uSgsT2eoxgA.tbRsulZc7lCYW7dq6DhtOMd-avoN19Q [form_charset] => UTF-8 )`


i got this array after executing the following code of line...
print_r($_REQUEST);  exit;

Comment: I mean thats the response i got...

Comment: Have you checked IPN implementation ? https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf

Comment: can i know when to use

`_xclick-subscriptions`

and 

when to use

`_xclick`